# HTML Canvas floating effect

Tags: html, animation, canvas

**Possible fix (efficency/perfomance issue over time?)**

```
let i = 0; 
function float() { 
    yPos += Math.sin(i); 
    i += .01 * yVel; 
}
```

I'm trying to re-create the "floating" effect in HTML5 Canvas. 
What I am trying to do is trying to get an image to "float" up and down.
The image is drawn and the the float() function is run to calculate the next y-position of the image. I have gotten it to float down, or up, but not how to change the direction after the image has floated example 100px (up or down). How would I do this?

I've uploaded the canvas here: https://stuff.darkleaks.net/HTML5%20WP/cheshire/

Ass you can see, the image floats down, and slows down. After it stops moving I want to change the floating direction. The `float()` function is where I try to do this.

```
   // Request animation frame
    const requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Canvas
    const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    // Set full-screen
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Framerate settings
    // Better not touch theese if you
    // do not know what you are doing
    let fps = (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 29 : 60;
    let now, delta;
    let then = Date.now();
    const interval = 1000 / fps;

    // Preparation below this comment line
    const background = new Image();
    const cheshire = new Image();
    const images = [background, cheshire];
    var imagesCount = images.length;

    background.onload = cheshire.onload;
    background.src = 'bg.png';
    cheshire.src = 'cheshire.png';

    let originalXPos = c.width / 2 - images[1].width / 2;
    let originalYPos = c.height / 2 - images[1].height / 2;
    let xPos = c.width / 2 - images[1].width / 2;
    let yPos = c.height / 2 - images[1].height / 2;
    let xVel = 0;
    let yVel = .5;

    // Draw
    function draw() {

        // Loop
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        now = Date.now();
        delta = now - then;

        if (delta > interval) {

            // Calculate then
            then = now - (delta % interval);

            // All your own stuff here
            drawImages();
            float();

        }

    }

    // Draw background
    function drawImages() {
        ctx.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0)
        ctx.drawImage(images[1], xPos, yPos);
    }

    function float() {

        yPos += 1 / yVel;
        yVel += .05;

        // IF the image has floated 100 px (up or down)
        // change direction

    }

    // Returns an random integer between
    // min and max
    function randInt(min, max) {
        max = max === undefined ? min - (min = 0) : max;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    // Cursor coordinates X & Y
    function clicked(e) {

        let x, y;

        if (e.offsetX) {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
        } else if (e.layerX) {
            x = e.layerX;
            y = e.layerY;
        }

        // Do something...

    }

    $('canvas').on('click', function(e) {
        clicked(e);
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);nter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

To float down in your code as given in the question

```
// in the draw function
xPos += xVel;
yPos += yVel;
```

Then check if the `yPos` is past some point and if so change direction

```
const bottom = ctx.canvas.height - 300; // put somewhere with globals 
if(yPos > bottom){ // is pos past bottom
   yVel = -0.5; // change direction
   yPos = bottom; // make sure yPos does not render past bottom
}
```

The same for the top

```
const top = 100; // put somewhere with globals 
if(yPos < top){ // is pos past top
   yVel = 0.5; // change direction
   yPos = top; // make sure yPos does not render past top
}
```

Comment: Found a little better solution. I don't really know if it's efficient because `i` will become very large over time.

But the solution I've got now is this:

let i = 0; function float() { yPos+=Math.sin(i); i+= .01 * yVel; }